# Can you make tandoori rotis with chickpea / green pea flour?

Tags: indian-cuisine

I would like to know if it is at all possible to make tandoori roti with chick-pea or green pea flour. Also is it just as simple as grinding dry peas into fine dust and using it as a substitute for flour or is there more to it than that. Also, what would you use as binding agent?

Comment: related - [Pesarattu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesarattu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a sort of bread with chickpea flour. It's a bit dense compared to a regular chapatti or roti & I'm not sure how much good it would be for picking up your main dish.

By volume, use 50:50 ratio flour to water, add salt to taste. Mix, pour onto baking paper on a flat try & bake at 200 until the sides start to brown. 15 - 20 mins.

Given the choice, I'd make pakora or bhajis instead. The batter fluffs up better deep fried than in the oven.

Chick pea flour is also called gram flour or besan &, at least in the UK, can now be found in any supermarket.
I've never used green pea flour, so can't really comment.

Comment: fascinating, this the type of food that warms my vegan heart (-;

Comment: tbh, I'm not even vegetarian - but I do love a good pakora or bhaji, onion & a bit of regular madras curry powder. Dead simple. With mint sauce just like 'mamma used to make' or, my local takeaway in Bradford ;-))

Answer (score 5):

I've made chapatis with gram flour. They worked nicely, but unlike wheat chapatis they didn't reheat well in a microwave or frying pan, ending up rather brittle, though they were fine when freshly made.

I can't find the recipe, but it was a very simple one: gram flour, a little oil, and just enough water to make a dough. Dry fry in a hot pan, and keep warm wrapped in foil while you make the rest.

Known as *missi roti* chickpea flour roti are apparently [traditional in some parts of India](https://www.vegrecipesofindia.com/missi-roti-recipe/)  though they normally use wheat flour as well.

Comment: ahh, interesting - so they do come up flexible enough to eat with, at least when fresh. Might have to give this one a try some time. I never found the oven-bake version particularly appetising & it can be a bit stiff, hence my usual bhaji/pakora preference.